# Find unique solutions of N-queens puzzle recursive algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, n-queens

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def puzzle(rows, cols):
    if rows == 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return new_queen(rows - 1, cols, puzzle(rows - 1, cols))


def new_queen(new_row, cols, plsd_queens):
    new_solutions = []
    for solution in plsd_queens:
        for new_col in range(cols):
            if test(new_row, new_col, solution):
                new_solutions.append(solution + [new_col])
    return new_solutions


def test(new_row, new_col, solution):
    for row in range(new_row):
        if solution[row] == new_col or solution[row] + row == new_col + new_row or\
                                solution[row] - row == new_col - new_row:
            return False
    return True
```

Hello all! How can I find the unique solutions of this recursive algorithm of N-queens puzzle?
It finds only all solutions: on board 8x8 it will be 92 solutions, but unique is only 12 (the other solutions are translations and mirrored from this 12)

Comment: Take the set of all solutions and compare two solutions for uniqueness.

Comment: Why not deal with uniqueness after taking all the solutions?

Comment: @czarpino, interesting, and how can I do this?

Comment: @amink, nothing. And I don't know how to solve this puzzle for unique solutions

Comment: do you understand my example for array A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these is usefull:
[link1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)
[link2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4_QnaTIxkQ)

For Best result you should design your algorithm by dynomic-programing and can find it in:
[google](https://www.google.com/search?q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&pq=n%20queens%20problem&cp=19&gs_id=11d&xhr=t&q=n%20queens%20problem%20dynamic%20programming&es_nrs=true&pf=p&client=firefox-a&hs=MGW&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&oq=n%20queens%20problem%20dy&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE&fp=218e9ca5fa938e68&biw=1366&bih=665)
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055891/8-queen-problem-using-dynamic-programming)

you set an array a[n][count] and save state i in a[..][i].
this is sample for item first by n=8 :

a = {5,1,8,4,2,7,3,6}{1} , .....

Note: each solution can changed to 8 state by symmetry and rotation.So for each result you symmetry and rotation their solution to check is that save in your array or not?