# What can be a newbie explanation for a dynamic programming?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am trying to learn the basics of Dynamic Programming (DP), and went through some the online resources i could get, such as...

1. [What is dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065433/what-is-dynamic-programming)
2. [Good examples, articles, books for understanding dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278188/good-examples-articles-books-for-understanding-dynamic-programming)
3. [Tutorial for Dynamic Programming](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-dynamic-programming)
4. [Dynamic Programming – From Novice to Advanced](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/) -- (I can't understand it properly (i.e. how to approach a problem using DP))

and till now i get to understand that

> A dynamic problem is almost same that of
>   recursion with just a difference (**which gives it the power it is know**
>   **for**)
>
> i.e. **storing the value or solution we got and using it again to find next solution**

For Example:

According to an explanation from codechef

**Problem : Minimum Steps to One**

**Problem Statement:** On a positive integer, you can perform any one of the following 3 steps.

1. Subtract 1 from it. ( n = n - 1 )
2. If its divisible by 2, divide by 2. ( if n % 2 == 0 , then n = n / 2  )
3. If its divisible by 3, divide by 3. ( if n % 3 == 0 , then n = n / 3  )

Now the question is, given a positive integer n, find the minimum number of steps that takes n to 1

eg:

1. For n = 1 , output: 0
2. For n = 4 , output: 2  ( 4  /2 = 2  /2 = 1 )
3. For n = 7 , output: 3  (  7  -1 = 6   /3 = 2   /2 = 1 )

   int memo[n+1]; // we will initialize the elements to -1 ( -1 means, not solved it yet )

Top-Down Approach for the above problem

```
int getMinSteps ( int n ) {
    if ( n == 1 )  return 0;
    if( memo[n] != -1 ) return memo[n];
    int r = 1 + getMinSteps( n - 1 );
    if( n%2 == 0 )   r  =  min( r , 1 + getMinSteps( n / 2 ) );
    if( n%3 == 0 )   r  =  min( r , 1 + getMinSteps( n / 3 ) );
    memo[n] = r ;  // save the result. If you forget this step, then its same as plain recursion.
    return r;
}
```

Am i correct in understanding the dp, or can anyone explain it in a better and easy way, so that i can learn it and can approach a problem with Dynamic programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence) example from wikipedia gives a good example.

Dynamic programming is an optimization technique that transforms a potentially exponential recursive solution into a polynomial time solution assuming the problem satisfies the [**principle of optimality**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation#Bellman.27s_Principle_of_Optimality). Basically meaning you can build an optimal solution from optimal sub-problems.
Another important characteristic of problems that are tractable with dynamic programming is that they are [**overlapping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems). If those problems are broken down into sub-problems that are repetitive, the same solution can be reused for solving those sub problems.
A problem with optimal substructure property and overlapping subproblems, dynamic programming is a potentially efficient way to solve it.

In the example you can see that recursive version of the Fibonacci numbers would grow in a tree like structure, suggesting an exponential explosion.

```
function fib(n)
       if n <=1 return n
       return fib(n − 1) + fib(n − 2)
```

So for `fib(5)` you get:

```
fib(5)
fib(4) + fib(3)
(fib(3) + fib(2)) + (fib(2) + fib(1))
```

And so on in a tree like fashion.

Dynamic programming lets us build the solution incrementally using optimal sub-problems in polynomial time. This is usually done with some form of record keeping such as a table.
Note that there are repeating instances of sub problems, i.e. calculating fib(2) one time is enough.

Also from Wikipedia, a dynamic programming solution

```
function fib(n)
   if n = 0
       return 0
   else
       var previousFib := 0, currentFib := 1
       repeat n − 1 times // loop is skipped if n = 1
           var newFib := previousFib + currentFib
           previousFib := currentFib
           currentFib  := newFib
   return currentFib
```

Here the solution is built up from `previousFib` and `currentFib` which are set initially. The `newFib` is calculated from the previous steps in this loop. `previousFib` and `currentFib` represent our record keeping for previous sub-problems.

The result is a polynomial time solution (O(n) in this case) for a problem whose recursive formulation would have been exponential (O(2^n) in this case).

Answer (score 0):

There is wonderful answer [How should I explain dynamic programming to a 4-year-old?](https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-explain-dynamic-programming-to-a-4-year-old/answer/Jonathan-Paulson)
Just quoting same here :

> Writes down "1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 =" on a sheet of paper
>
> "What's that equal to?"
>
> *counting* "Eight!"
>
> *writes down another "1+" on the left*
>
> "What about that?"
>   *quickly* "Nine!"
>
> "How'd you know it was nine so fast?"
>
> "You just added one more"
>
> "So you didn't need to recount because you remembered there were
>   eight! **Dynamic Programming is just a fancy way to say 'remembering
>   stuff to save time later'**"